# .Net core 3.1 sudenly stoped thowing HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-3.1, windows-server-2019

Everything was fine until yesterday. This must be due to Windows update. No one touched the server. I have tired couple of similar solutions posted in Stack Overflow(all are old questions),none of them worked for me. What I have, Server Windows server 2019, APP netcore 3.1 ,IIS version 10. .net core runtime and SDK both are installed. This was working before. No one touched anything, just stopped working

In the browser appearing
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
[image]

When I executed on the command line

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in

[image]

When I checked event log. Something like below appeared. But let me tell you in the build
directory we don't have a file like app.runtimeconfig.json
[image]
[image]

**What I have tried**

1. Repair .netcoe runtime and SDK
2. Restore old DB backup
3. Reinstall .netcore versions
4. No pending Windows updates
5. Restart IIS APP pool also the server
6. Check file permission

None of them worked for me. If anyone can help, really appreciate.

Comment: Make sure you download [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and install it on your server, If it still doesn't work, you can use failed request tracing to get detailed error information.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, we can't find out that the environment of windows server caused by windows update is abnormal. As you said, it worked fine before.

So please allow me summarize below suggestions as answer.

**Suggestions**

1. Copy the `publish file` named `original_file`  . And paste it in our dev pc or other server which have IIS Management. And test it, this publish file should be works. This step just confirm the publish file is normal.
2. Create a new website and a new application pool. Create a new `asp.net core3.1` application and deploy it. Then check if it works properly under this new site.
3. The site should be fine in the second steps, and replace it with the `original_file`. And the application also should be works fine.
4. The site can't work in the second steps, it means the environment in you server has some problem. It could be `registry issue` or `ApplicationHost.config` issue in IIS and so on.  If it's very important for you, you can rasie a support ticket and let official engineer help you to figure out what happend in this windows Update
5. After the third step, if the new site can run the `original_file` file well. We can compare ApplicationHost.config between the new site and the original one to see if any settings have been changed.